# How can I get unlimited google text to speech service?

Tags: google-translate

I'm going to use Google translate text-to-speech for my application. Defaultly Google TTS just allowing < 100 chars/request.
But I need more than 100 chars/request. How can I get it? Does Google Translate API (paid version) gives text-to-speech service which give me unlimited chars/request?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Translate API FAQ found on Google's website [1], the maximum size of text that can be translated per request is 5000. Doesn't mention anything about unlimited so it's not an option.
If you go to the link below, there are also instructions on how to increase the limit in the Developers Console

Hope this help.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/faq#technical